# Filter rows based on elements in a string split after splitting (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas `DataFrame` containing a column with semicolon-separated location names:

```
index   locations
39951   Credit; Mount Pleasant GO
40976   Ajax GO; Whitby GO; Credit; Oshawa GO; Bayly
14961   Credit; Mount Pleasant GO; Port Credit GO
...
```

What I would like to do is filter based on whether a specified location appears in the semicolon-separated list, by splitting the string first (on the `;`) and then checking if a location is in the list.

Using `str.contains()` doesn't work here because there are overlapping location names (`Credit` appears both in `Credit` and `Port Credit` for example), and a row with a single location will not have a `;` so I can't search for `Credit;`. I've tried things like

```
df["Credit" in df.locations.str.split("; ")]
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex `(^|;) *Credit(;|$)` to make sure the pattern is exclusive between separators, so *Credit* will be either at start or end of string or directly follow or followed by separator `;`:

```
df
   index                                     locations
0  39951                     Credit; Mount Pleasant GO
1  40976  Ajax GO; Whitby GO; Credit; Oshawa GO; Bayly
2  14961             Mount Pleasant GO; Port Credit GO

df.locations.str.contains('(^|;) *Credit(;|$)')
#0     True
#1     True
#2    False
#Name: locations, dtype: bool
```

If you further want to ignore case, add modifier `?i` to the pattern:

```
df.locations.str.contains('(?i)(^|;) *credit(;|$)')
#0     True
#1     True
#2    False
#Name: locations, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Clever, and likely faster than a 2-step filter as suggested by Anurag's answer I would imagine?

Comment: Yeah it should be since it doesn't require splitting. A brief benchmark shows regex takes half time as split and filtering. You can have your own benchmark if you are also interested.

Answer (score 1):

You can try(without regex):

```
#split and explode the dataframe:
m=df['locations'].str.split('; ').explode()
#check your condition and get index where condition satisfies:
m=m[m.isin(['Credit'])].index.unique()
#Finally filter out dataframe:
out=df.loc[m]
```

Now If you print `out` you will get filtered dataframe